# Change Combo color on focus

Tags: html, css, primefaces

I want to change border color on focus for combo box. It has class .ui-selectonemenu class and on focus ui-state-focus class gets applied to same level. I am trying to write selector as .ui-selectonemenu .ui-state-focus and tried .ui-selectonemenu :focus but both are not working. Any suggestions. Doing it for primefaces

Comment: try to put relevant code on http://jsbin.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
.ui-selectonemenu
            {
                width:150px;
                padding:5px;
            }
.ui-selectonemenu:hover, .ui-selectonemenu:focus
            {
                background:#ffd800;
                border:px solid #f00;
            }
```